# Bash !#:3 what does this do?

Tags: bash

I see the following command

```
curl http://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.14-single-file > ~/bin/ack && chmod 0755 !#:3
```

What does !#:3 do in chmod? obviously it's changing permissions mask on ~/bin/ack but can someone please explain, never seen this before?

Comment: Hint: search for `[bash] code:"!#"`. The "code" part is key and it is new. Otherwise, it was impossible to find such texts in here.

Comment: Thank you very much, awesome nerdy stuff... Basically means "substitute the value in the 3rd column into chmod" (so no need to type ~/bin/ack twice, I guess learning what !#: means is easier than years of shell command repetition, which is true)

Comment: Yeah it is nerdy stuff to avoid typing too much :)

Comment: ...nerdy stuff that's not usable in scripts (interactive shells only), so arguably belongs on SuperUser or Unix SE, not here (since [StackOverflow's scope](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is limited to items "unique to software development").